# Security for DataBase password and user login password in Spring and Java Encoder How to?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Good day folks. I have application witch works with database(Hibernate) and Spring MVC. The problem is that I store all passwords in app-config file for datasource:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"> <!-- Using and configuring C3P0 proxy -->
        <property name="driverClass"><value>org.h2.Driver</value></property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>jdbc:h2:/home/vadim/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/h2/EDUCATION</value></property>
        <property name="user"><value>sa</value></property>
        <property name="password">password<value></value></property>
        <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>3</value></property> <!-- Number of Connections a pool will try to acquire upon startup -->
        <property name="minPoolSize"><value>1</value></property> <!-- Minimum connection pool size -->
        <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>20</value></property> <!-- Max connection pool size -->
        <property name="maxConnectionAge"><value>3600</value></property> <!-- Set max connection age to 1 hour, after it will release -->
        <property name="maxIdleTime"><value>600</value></property> <!-- 10 minutes connection can stay unused before be discarded -->
        <property name="checkoutTimeout"><value>200000</value></property> <!-- Each what time check for unused connections -->
        </bean>
```

And login passwords of user and admin in security-context:

```
<security:authentication-manager>
<security:authentication-provider>
<security:password-encoder hash="sha-256" base64="true"/>
<security:user-service>
<security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
<security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</security:user-service>
</security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

How can I protect them for any other eyes and I have to make custom encoder to protect them from any other types of attacks with Message Digest Spring or java security. And The encoder Algorithm  is a part of service or front-end layer??? Witch layer have to has my realization of encoder. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encrypt properties, consider using [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/index.html), it integrates with [Spring](http://www.jasypt.org/spring3.html) and [Spring Security](http://www.jasypt.org/springsecurity.html). For example you can define encrypted properties:

```
datasource.password=ENC(G6N718UuyPE5bHyWKyuLQSm02auQPUtm)
```

Then create a `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean, which allows you refer to the properties as you normally would - they are decrypted for you:

```
...
<property name="password" value="${datasource.password}"/>
...
```

It's not exactly as described by your sample, but it may be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you Sir for you amazing answer. I'm not strong in encryption problems, just as I post, what about other part like sha-256 in security-context.xml. Does it applicable to user and admin password, does it have to  check for admin, user password in sha-256 variant with something else. just how it suppose to work?? And is more o service layer or front-end layer??

Comment: It's been a while since I used Spring Security, perhaps you could parameterise the value also? E.g. `password="${user.password}"`.

Comment: Hey. If I will use JackSum to make sha from my cleartext password. Does it great idea, and how it;s going to work, nobody can make  decryption back to cleartext. And what about my database password I use H2 by the way. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid I don't feel comfortable offering advice on encryption. I urge you to do more research, or post further questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I just understand that hashing  is not what I want because it proved data integrity. Confused about it. But encryption hide my data. Way I use sha-256 hashing to hide my password instead encryption.

Comment: @USER_JVM [This](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Cryptography#Algorithm_Selection) may help regarding algorithm selection.

Comment: Thank you Sir. This is really interesting.

Answer (score 0):

For most modern applications, the true secret is the key or password, rather than the algorithm.

You can use [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) to encrypt the user/password or other properties in the spring configuration files. Jasypt has also [dedicated spring integration](http://www.jasypt.org/spring31.html) such as a PropertySource or PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: Thank you Sir for you awesome answer. I'm not strong in encryption problems, just as I post, what about other part like sha-256 in security-context.xml. Does it applicable to user and admin password, does it have to  check for admin, user password in sha-256 variant with something else. just how it suppose to work??